# Javascript Array Random Got Zero

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get random number between 0 and Array.length.
I have this:

```
getRandom() {
  const cars = Object.keys(this.index);
  const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length);
  return cars[randomInt];
}
```

I ran this few times and found a `0` in one of the results from `getRandom()`. There is not `key` in my `this.index` object named `0`.

Is my math function wrong?

**UPDATE**

After reading the comments, and I know the `getRandom()` is not wrong. I also have `reset()` function if you guys can look at it.

```
reset() {
  const cars = Object.keys(this.index);
  let i = cars.length;
  while (i--) {
    this.index[cars[i]] = 0;
  }
}
```

Is it possible I'm adding a new key `0` at `this.index` object?

Comment: The function is not wrong, but your expectations might be. What are valid random values?

Comment: `Math.random()` can return `0`. so this `Math.floor(Math.random() * cars.length);` can end up being `0`

Comment: `cars` is an array. Unless it is empty, it has an entry at index 0. That entry (not the 0 itself) should be a valid key of `this.index`.

Comment: `Object.keys` returns array, `cars[randomInt]` gonna return you `randomInt`'th element of array

Comment: Also, `Math.floor(0.49) `= 0

Comment: You probably wanted `return this.index[cars[randomInt]]` on the last line.

Comment: You can make use of this existing solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range
And pass 0 and array.length as params.

Comment: There's a bit of confusing information in your question.. do you want the function to return the random number, a random key from the `this.index` object or a random property from that object?

Comment: @geekonaut I'm trying to get a random keyname from object `this.index`. All I need is the keyname.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see an actual problem here.

`Object.keys` will turn your named `keys` into numbers (look here https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), this numbers starts with 0.

So your function, as you wrote yourselv, will return an:

> random number between 0 and Array.length

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of this existing solution.

[Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-whole-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

And pass 0 and array.length as params.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder what you're seeing, but we're all lacking context here, so I made a little example to try the function to see the problem with my own eyes and it does not seem to have the problem you described.

[Try it for yourself here](http://jsbin.com/femiza/edit?js,console) - and maybe it's the data you're running the method on that is the problem?